# convert iso-8601 datetime to utc time rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, datetime, time, iso8601

I have an ISO-8601 datetime stamp, and need to convert it into local time in GMT. What is the way to do it in Ruby on Rails? I have `'1325233011'`, and need to convert it into local time in GMT standards.

Comment: You have a contradition local time <> GMT. What do you want now?

Comment: I need GMT+5 time, but first preference is converting this string to gmt time, Thanks for response

Comment: Sawa what are you doing man instead of answering you are doing childish things.

Comment: Sawa is improving your question's grammar, because it wasn't well written. His action was hardly childish, it was to help you. Please read "[Other people can edit my posts?!](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#editing)" for more information.

Comment: Ok My apologies sawa, thanks for improving grammer :) and thanks to you @the Tin Man

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what you're asking for is a locale time in GMT+5.

Given an ISO timestamp, 1325233011

When I convert this to a locale-based date/time

```
Time.at(1325233011) => '2011-12-30 03:16:51 -0500'
```

Take a look at the ruby-docs, http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Time.html for more information. Ruby has robust Time and Date classes with many helper utilities. My machine is configured for GMT-5 so it returns the local time. It's easy to change the way timezone settings are interpreted in your program, but that's for another day. Hope this helps!

Comment: thanks @user1863592 but I got your answer when I find mine I also upovter your answer as you responded instantly and accuratly thanks :)

Answer (score -1):

From Collegue's help got it

```
Time.at(1325233011).to_datetime
```

**For Iso-8601:**

```
Time.at(1325233011).to_datetime.iso8601
```

For verification of time correct conversion and comparision use this link
http://coderstoolbox.net/unixtimestamp/