# how to convert ISO 8601 to Date time(Utc) in Python

Tags: python, datetime, iso8601

I have time stamp in ISO format "2022-06-19T00:00:00+00:00"

and want to convert it in to Date time(utc) format "Jun 19, 2022"

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I parse an ISO 8601-formatted date?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/127803/how-do-i-parse-an-iso-8601-formatted-date)

Comment: After parsing to datetime object, just `strftime` with desired formatting directive.

Comment: @FObersteiner any library or method to parse iso to datetime

Comment: @FObersteiner [How do I parse an ISO 8601-formatted date?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14882908/convert-iso-8601-datetime-to-utc-time-rails) is in unix time stamp not in iso

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can be done using the built-in datetime module:

```
import datetime as dt

input_string = '2022-06-19T00:00:00+00:00'
date = dt.datetime.fromisoformat(input_string)
print(date.strftime('%b %d, %Y'))
```